# Vuejs populate select options from api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, materialize

Im begginer in VueJs so i have this problem

Here my code

```
<md-select placeholder="Seleccione Lote" v-model="selectedLote" name="lotes" id="lotes">
   <md-option  v-for="lote of lotes" value="lote.value">{{lote.text}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Then i have my array

```
data: () => ({
        lotes: [],
        selectedLote : null
    })
```

Then i populate this array using this (this.products is an array populated from an api request)

```
mounted(){
  this.fillLotesArray();
},
methods:{
fillLotesArray(){
            for(let product of this.products){
                if(this.lotes.findIndex(lote => lote.value === product._source.Lote) === -1){
                    this.lotes.push({value:product._source.Lote, text:product._source.Lote});
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Using console.logs i can see the array is filled correctly but the options dont

Comment: You could add a v-if="lotes" or you could make lotes a computed property.

Comment: Is this.products filled from the api request before the page is mounted or after?

Answer (score 1):

this is usually my standard way to write a select from an API

```
<template>
    <select v-model="selectedOption">
        <option v-for="(item, index) in options" :value="item.value" :key="index">{{ item.text }}</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ExampleOptions',
    data() {
        return {
            options: [],
            selectedOption: null,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadOptions();
    },
    methods: {
        loadOptions() {
            api.getOptions().then((options) => {
                this.options = options;
            });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

if you then need to have the data in correlation to others, such as a list of products or others, it is always advisable to use **computed properties**, to make sure that the data is always correct
[some examples](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-computed-properties-in-vue-js/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have the same code but it still doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

In Vue's repetition, a key is required.

v-bind is not set in value.

---

If you take {{lots}} and the value is expressed normally, try modifying the following.

```
<md-option  v-for="(lote, index) of lotes" :value="lote.value" :key="index">{{lote.text}}</md-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to bind the select options value attribute

```
<md-select placeholder="Selection Lote" v-model="selectedLote" name="lotes" id="lotes">
   <md-option  v-for="(lote, index) of lotes" :value="lote.value" :key="index">{{lote.text}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

For detailed usage of the `key` attribute, please see the `key` [API documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key).